# Can't post user's "message" with Achievement

Tags: facebook-graph-api, achievements

I have a Facebook Game called "Physi Bricks". The game has achievements. When the user gets an achievement, I ask if they would like to post a message with that achievement. If they click "yes" they are prompted for a message. This message is then attached to the achievement when I submit it to Facebook with my app token.

When the user doesn't choose to include a message, the Achievement is submitted successfully.

When the user chooses to include a message I get this error back from Facebook:

"**Application with ID 347432048676550 has not been granted the capability to use the property message.**"

According to the Facebook Documentation for [Creating an Achievement for a User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/), I can publish the "message" parameter, provided I have the "publish_actions" permission, which I do have.

How/where can I be granted the capability to use the "message" property?

Comment: When you are doing the access_token exchange you need to ask for all the permissions you want so your application can interact with Facebook on behalf of your user. Check out this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: I looked at the link. The only Extended Permission that I could ask for that might let me use the "message" parameter when submitting an Achievement is publish_stream. However, publish_stream would let me do a ton more than that. I am currently asking for the publish_actions, and email permissions. According to the Achievements documentation, I only need publish_actions to publish the "message" parameter (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/)